# How do I simplify this code with an Array and counting int up in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#, rotation, movement, waypoints

I want to simplify my code. I had the idea of making an Array of waypoints[] and and int i to count up each time I arrive a new point of waypoint but it should be the same way my code is but instead of waypoint1.position... waypoint3.position I thought it should be like waypoint[i].position and it counts up everytime I reach another waypoint this would simplify a lot and would make the code much shorter.
The code is for moving an Object from A to B from B to C and so on..

I commented some lines how it would look like but ignore the //MOVE //ROTATE comments

Code:

---

```
public float speed;
public float turnSpeed;

//Starting with these somehow
//public Transform[] waypoints;
//private int i = 0;

public Transform player;
public Transform waypoint;
public Transform waypoint1;
public Transform waypoint2;
public Transform waypoint3;

public bool b0 = true;
public bool b1 = false;
public bool b2 = false;
public bool b3 = false;
public bool b4 = false;

void FixedUpdate () 
{
        if(b0)
        {
            //MOVE
            player.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(player.position, waypoint.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
            //ROTATE
            var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(waypoint.position - player.position);
            player.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(player.rotation, rotation, turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

            float distance = Vector3.Distance(player.position, waypoint.position);
            //Debug.Log (Mathf.Round(distance));
            if(distance <= 1)
            {
                // i++;
                b1 = true;
                b0 = false;
            }
        }

        if(b1)
        {
            //MOVE
            player.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(player.position, waypoint1.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
            //ROTATE
            var rotation1 = Quaternion.LookRotation(waypoint1.position - player.position);
            player.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(player.rotation, rotation1, turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

            float distance1 = Vector3.Distance(player.position, waypoint1.position);
            //Debug.Log (Mathf.Round(distance1));
            if(distance1 <= 1)
            {
                b1 = false;
                b2 = true;
            }
        }

        if(b2)
        {
            //MOVE
            player.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(player.position, waypoint2.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
            //ROTATE
            var rotation2 = Quaternion.LookRotation(waypoint2.position - player.position);
            player.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(player.rotation, rotation2, turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

            float distance2 = Vector3.Distance(player.position, waypoint2.position);
            //Debug.Log (Mathf.Round(distance1));
            if(distance2 <= 1)
            {
                b2 = false;
                b3 = true;
            }
        }

        if(b3)
        {
            //MOVE
            player.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(player.position, waypoint3.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
            //ROTATE
            var rotation3 = Quaternion.LookRotation(waypoint3.position - player.position);
            player.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(player.rotation, rotation3, turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

            float distance3 = Vector3.Distance(player.position, waypoint3.position);
            //Debug.Log (Mathf.Round(distance1));
            if(distance3 <= 1)
            {
                b3 = false;
                b4 = true;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: You could make Waypoint into an object. That way it has internal state like "passed"/"not passed". Would make a lot of things easier in the future (i. e. the goal having a different color). Sorry fot not responding to your original question but I'm on mobile atm

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps

```
public float speed;
public float turnSpeed;

public Transform player;

public Transform[] waypoints;
private int currentlyActive = 0;

void FixedUpdate () 
{
    if(waypoints.Length >= currentlyActive)
    {
        return;
    }
    waypoint = waypoints[currentlyActive];
    player.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(player.position, waypoint.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(waypoint.position - player.position);
    player.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(player.rotation, rotation, turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    float distance = Vector3.Distance(player.position, waypoint.position);
    if(distance <= 1)
    {
        currentlyActive++;
    }
}
```

Haven't tested it in unity but it should be the transformation you asked for.

I recommend looking at how others have solved this problem. Often you can see APIs or programming techniques you don't know yet.
Also there are many C# or Unity Books :)

Comment: I got it by my own however I just declared public GameObject[] waypoints; and private int currentWp = 0;

and then I just replaced the waypoint.position with waypoints[currentWp].transform.position and if the distance is smaller than a number currentWp++; this seemed to work.

Comment: But thanks your code brought me up to an idea how it could work :)

Comment: glad to hear :)